# C++ empty virtual function with unknown parameter type

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say I have a class that handles events. Since I don't know what engine I will use, I don't know the type of the event. Then I want to create a child for the handler class specifically prepared for a specific engine that then defines exact type of argument. Is this possible? If so, how?

In short: is the following code correct?

```cpp
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void handle_event(void* e) = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void handle_event(SomeEngineEvent e)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work.  You need to use the same parameter type in both base and derived classes.

What you want to do here is defined an interface (or base class) that all engines use, and then use that as the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles...

but

`void Derived::handle_event(SomeEngineEvent)` doesn't override `void Base::handle_event(void*)` but hides it.

So `Derived` is still abstract.

template might be an option,

```
template <typename Event>
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void handle_event(Event) = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base<SomeEngineEvent>
{
    void handle_event(SomeEngineEvent e) override
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
};
```

but hard to tell without more info.